# Where is the C++ source code located in the Orange package?

Tags: python, orange

In Orange, I learn the low-level computationally intensive procedures like data filtering, probability assessment and feature scoring are written in C++, and the high-level algorithms such as classification tree learning are written in Python. However, I don't find any C++ code in the Orange 2.7 distribution package. Does anyone know where the Orange C++ source code is located or if it is not included in the package? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In the source package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mostly always find up-to-date version of [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) software in the version control repository the team uses.

For Orange 2.7 that's https://github.com/biolab/orange (find most C++ files in the "source" dir).

For (current) Orange 3: https://github.com/biolab/orange3 (there appears to be little C++ there; mostly replaced with calls to other libraries (SciPy, Scikit-learn, ...) and Cython (*.pyx) modules).

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind answer and information!

Comment: If you are happy with any of the answers, you can and should [mark it as _accepted_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

```
curl https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/O/Orange/Orange-2.7.8.tar.gz | tar zxvf -
find Orange-2.7.8/ -name \*.cpp
```

You see some cpp files in `Orange-2.7.8/source/orangeom`

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer and great information!